# Can't have access to the file in Datalab's container from Jupyter python cell

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

I successfully migrate my data from the deprecated Cloud Datalab Deployer to the docker Datalab container with GCP. I'm using MacOS and I can see that my home directory is connected to container's `/content` directory. So my notebooks are accessible in the Datalab Jupyter interface.

My notebooks have some text processing routine which loads a stop word list from a text file located just in the same directory as the notebook itself.
But when I try to have access to one of the files in `/content` directory from python code, I receive an error 'File does not exist':

```
>>> stopwords_full = load_stopwords_from_file('./stopwords/verylong_words_list.txt')

IOError: File ./stopwords/verylong_words_list.txt does not exist
```

Indeed, when I run `ls` command I can't see `/content` directory with all its subfiles etc:

```
>>> !ls
bin  dev   lib    mnt       proc  sbin  sys    usr
boot     etc   lib64  node_modules  root  srcs  tmp    var
datalab  home  media  opt       run   srv   tools
```

In the old version of Datalab I didn't have such an error.

How can I work with files in the container's `/content` directory from the Datalab Jupyter python cells?

Comment: When using Datalab on GCP I found that `!hostname` shows the host name of the datalab gateway. If I use the [Datalab local](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-local) setup, I see the hostname of my local container. I can access local files and see the `content` folder when I run `!ls`. One potential work around for accessing files when using Datalab on GCP is to use Google Cloud Storage. There is an example at the [following link](https://github.com/googledatalab/notebooks/blob/master/tutorials/BigQuery/Importing%20and%20Exporting%20Data.ipynb) which could be helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AnthoniosPartheniou ! Seems like going with Google Cloud Storage will solve my issue. Do you know if it is possible to use `git` with GCS (our team shared notebooks through Google Cloud Source Repositories)? I found a `gsutil rsync` [workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29859651/sync-github-repository-with-google-cloud-storage-bucket), but maybe there is some more straightforward solution.

Comment: Although the kernel is in GCP, the notebooks reside on your local machine. You can continue to use Google Cloud Source Repositories. Simply [clone the repository](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/adding-repositories-as-remotes) to your local machine. Change `-v "${HOME}:/content"` in your `docker run...` command. Replace the text `${HOME}` with the path to the folder containing your notebooks. Google Drive is an alternate way to share notebooks since you can share/sync folders with your team. My personal preference is to use Cloud Source Repositories with a local git client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding my comment as the answer so that this doesn't appear as an unanswered question:

When using Datalab on GCP I found that `!hostname` shows the host name of the datalab gateway. If I use the [Datalab local](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-local) setup, I see the hostname of my local container. Using the Datalab local setup, I can access local files and see the content folder when I run `!ls`. One potential work around for accessing files when using Datalab on GCP is to use Google Cloud Storage. There is an example at the [following link](https://github.com/googledatalab/notebooks/blob/master/tutorials/BigQuery/Importing%20and%20Exporting%20Data.ipynb) which could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps one can also run 'git checkout' from a cell. This will in principle put your txt files inside the host vm and you can adjust your path for that.

We had to do all sort of hacks like this on the AppEng deployed version of Datalab, given that the git interface on GPC has been buggy. Not the perfect solution.

Also, seem like `gsutil` CLI call is available within a cell with `%%bash`. You can put file on a bucket and then copy inside VM with `gsutil`

Comment: Thanks for idea @JoseCelaya! I'll give it a try, but I have an impression that Compute Engine instance storage re-initialized every time after restart. Need to verify all scenarios...

Comment: @AlexanderUsoltsev Yes, that is likely the case. For every GCE resource, google re-deploys them every once in a while. Actually this was an issue with the AppEngine version of Cloud Datalab. Every once in a while, google would redeploy (not restart only) the underlying VM and everything that we have installed was wiped. What we ended up doing, is to define a notebook with all the installation calls using the %%bash magic function. On the day after redeployment, our stuff would not work and we took that as a hint to go and re-install all the packages.

Comment: The compute engine instances used by Datalab instance are indeed ephemeral. One of the notebooks used in Google's cloud training, [CPB100](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/blob/8bde4de393bfdd1d91231a27776f1962577305ed/CPB100/lab4c/mlapis.ipynb), contains a system command to pip install the Google APIs to use the ML APIs from a notebook (second cell down). It's hacky, but notebook magic seems like the best approach for now.

Comment: Alternatively, you could customize the Datalab docker image, as described on the [Datalab github repo wiki](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/wiki/Getting-Started), and bundle it with the data or packages you need. Push the container to their container registry, then use the `--image-name` flag when you start Datalab.